# Creating a link to google maps including data in specific SQL database field - Lightswitch

Tags: javascript, html, sql, maps, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have created a lightswitch project and have linked it to an SQL database.

I need to create a link to google maps which will show the location of that exact record in my database.

I can't seem to program it to take my data though! The data source is called Demo_Stores_Lightswitch and the field I need to add to the end of the URL is called Address.

```
var st = $('<a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=" target="_blank">Link to Map</a>'); st.appendTo($(element));
```

I managed to get a pop up window to google maps with this code ^

I can never get lightswitch to use the data in my SQL database when I'm manually writing the code, drives me insane! Please help...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this works for me: (I am using Lightswitch HTML Client)

```
myapp.AddEditShippingTable.TEST_execute = function (screen) {

var postcode = screen.ShippingTable.ShippingPostcode;

window.open("https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/" + postcode);

};
```

and in addition for directions using Google Maps and a set location such as a place of work you can use the following:

```
myapp.AddEditShippingTable.TEST2_execute = function (screen) {

var postcode = screen.ShippingTable.ShippingPostcode;

window.open("https://www.google.co.uk/maps/dir/[POSTCODE]/" + postcode);

};
```

hope this helps